Unable to get a response after sending an HTTP request to a website
I'm trying to send an HTTP request to a website using the requests module, expecting to get a 200 status code. However, when I run the script, I always receive an error, which I will paste below. I've added the headers, but I still haven't received any response.
import requests

link = 'https://apps.hcr.ny.gov/BuildingSearch/'

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'host': 'apps.hcr.ny.gov',
    'origin': 'https://apps.hcr.ny.gov',
    'referer': 'https://apps.hcr.ny.gov/BuildingSearch/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,headers=headers)
    print(res.status_code)

I receive the following error:
  File "C:\Users\CL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 682, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))


can't reproduce

Even if you try the code here: https://pythonhow.com/python-shell, you should encounter the same error @folen gateis.

User-Agent NOT user-agent

i copy-pasted your code, launched it and got response 200

@SIGHUP User-Agent NOT user-agent - that shouldn't matter. either is fine

@chitown88 "shouldn't" but it does in this case. Change the headers dictionary so that it only has the User-Agent key/value then test with both mixed- and lower-case variants and see what happens

@SIGHUP - thanks for replying back with that update. The beauty of SO is we get to learn something new everyday. Thanks for the insights. Awesome stuff.

The website you're accessing is not RFC 7230 compliant. The server appears to be Microsoft-IIS/10.0
HTTP headers should be treated as case-insensitive.
Here's the proof:
import requests
import json

URL = 'https://apps.hcr.ny.gov/BuildingSearch/'
UA = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_7_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.4.1 Safari/605.1.15"

for key in "user-agent", "User-Agent":
    headers = {
        key: UA
    }
    print("\nTrying with:", json.dumps(headers, indent=2))
    try:
        with requests.get(URL, headers=headers) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            print("Success")
    except Exception:
        print("Failed")

Output:
Trying with: {
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_7_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.4.1 Safari/605.1.15"
}
Failed

Trying with: {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_7_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.4.1 Safari/605.1.15"
}
Success


Not all websites allow automated access
Hey @MITHU, the reason you are getting ConnectionError is because some websites simply don't allow automated access to prevent from bots.
You can check that by using webiste_url/robots.txt
Usually they would have something like below:
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

You can try out this working example:
import requests

url = 'https://github.com/'

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)

    response = session.get(url)

    print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
    print("Page Snippet:", response.text[:500]) 

